# Undo downvote after 10 minutes rule

Tags: support, voting, undo

I accidentally downvoted an answer, but didn't notice it by time to correct it. How can I undo it after the 10 minutes rule?

The answer I incorrectly downvoted: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49685250/4746087

Comment: If I recall correctly, after an edit, this possible. Do you see something, to improve on it?

Comment: do a trivial edit like adding a space

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Editing the post will "unlock" your vote, and you'll be able to remove your downvote.

If you can edit the answer and improve it, that would be the best course of action. If you can't, you could perform a trivial edit like adding a newline at the end of the answer, remove your downvote, and if you really want to be nice, edit the post again and remove the newline you just added.